# Is it okay to free a memory that was malloc'd in a different function?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, malloc, free

When I have the following for the main function, race happens because of i.

```
...
for(i = 0; i < 30; i++){
    pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, thread, &i);
}
...
```

To avoid this, I malloc'd a size of int and then used it to pass the argument instead of &i. And then I used the value and then freed it in the thread function. Does this correctly free without memory leak? (The following is the new code)

```
void *thread(void *vargp){
    int n = *((int *)vargp);
    free(vargp);
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    printf("%d\n",n);
}

void main(){
    int i;
    pthread_t tid[20];
    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        int *n = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
        *n = i;
        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, thread, n);
    }
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: There wouldn't be much of a point if you couldn't.

Comment: Every pointer you hand to `free` must be exactly a pointer you got back from `malloc` (or `realloc`), and that you haven't freed already.  Other than that, you can do just about anything you want.  Allocating in one place and freeing in another is a common practice, and depending on the circumstances, it can be absolutely the right thing to do.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer - yes. As long as everything you `malloc`ed is eventually `free`d once and only once, it doesn't matter that the `malloc` and `free` happen in different functions, or even different threads.

Comment: As thong as those functions are not statically linked to different implementations of CRT :)

Comment: You mean DLL's :)